How to set rules in vscode salesforce security scanner
I'd like to be able to set what rules run when running the Salesforce Security Scanner from within VSCode.  There are times when I'm solely interested in security issues and I want to filter out noise, that is, items related to style like the Apex Doc missing or module size.  From the command line, I use category Security as shown below...
sfdx scanner run --target . --format csv --category Security

Anyone know how to set that in VSCode?

Are you referring to the "Salesforce Code Analyzer" extension and looking for a variation on its "Scan ... with Code Analyzer" commands? Or would you just want to execute above command on the click of a button or with a keyboard shortcut? (You probably noticed the sf version of it.)

I would like to run the scanner by right-clicking on a file and selecting "SFDX: Scan current file with Code Analyzer."
If I run it that way, it runs a HUGE number of style rules (some of which I totally disagree with).  I'm hoping there is a settings file somewhere where I can set the command to only run the security scan, what would run if I ran it from the command like with "--category Security"

Open VSCode File - Preferences - Settings. Choose either User or Workspace. Navigate to Extensions - Salesforce Code Analyzer.
There is a section Code Analyzer › Rules: Category. Enter Security, for example ;-)
Official name of setting: codeAnalyzer.rules.category

That worked.  I found the easiest way to do it was simply to search for -- codeAnalyzer.rules.category -- in the settings.
